# Rails 5, production mode, enum error "ArgumentError is not a valid"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, enums, production-environment

My model:

```
class Job < ActiveRecord::Base
  enum job_type: [:point, :mass]
end
```

My controller:

```
Job.new job_type: 'mass'
```

Error log:

```
ArgumentError 'mass' is not a valid job_type.
```

It happens in production server only. And bug disappears after server restart and return back after few hours.

Versions: 
Rails 5.0.0.rc1, ruby 2.3.1

Comment: BTW, those are strange versions to be running on production. At the *very least*, you should upgrade to Rails `5.0.0` (ideally `5.0.5` or even `5.1.3`) and ruby `2.3.4` (ideally `2.4.1`).

Comment: How to fix it, of course :)

Comment: *"bug disappears after server restart and return back after few hours"* -- I have no idea how to reproduce your problem. The first step I would take, as suggested above, is to use a stable rails version on production and not an old release candidate.

Comment: The second step I'd take, if the problem still occurs, is to add some better logging and review the production config. (For example, could this be a class reloading issue, or conflicting model definitions, or an old server thread that's still referencing a previously deployed application version?)

Comment: How did you resolve this?

Answer (score -2):

you can use both string or symbol as job_type value it works fine on both.

```
class Book < ApplicationRecord
  enum name: [ :active, :archived ]
end
```

using symbol

```
Book.new(name: :archived) => #<Book id: nil, name: "archived", author_id: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
```

Using string

`Book.new(name: "archived")` =>

```
#<Book id: nil, name: "archived", author_id: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
```